# how to run an android application in netbeans

Tags: android, debugging, netbeans6.8

I would like to know how one could run an android application in netbeans specifically netbeans debugger. when I start  the emulator with a target device what do I do next. what do I do with myprogram.apk. what do I do in Netbeans. I am new to the whole concept and I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2012/12/configure-android-in-netbeans.html) and/or [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVSk_WDI-yY) for information on how to configure Netbeans for Android development. In my opinion you will probably be better off in the long run learning Android Studio.